# Iterating over a list of floats in a table in python

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I have a quick python problem.

I would like to extract the number "7" from a list of numbers within each cell of a column in a larger table. The number 7 denotes that the household being interviewed has a refrigerator.

This is my current code:

```
raw_data = pd.read_csv('raw_data.csv')

test = raw_data["s6q68_electric_appliance"]

def check_has_refrigerator(input_value):
    if "7" in input_value:
        return True
    return False

raw_data["has_refrigerator"] = test.apply(check_has_refrigerator)
```

However the above code does not work, as python is unable to iterate over floats. My question is, how can I change the values in each cell to be shown as a string to allow python to extract the number "7" within each cell. Within a given cell numbers are shown randomly e.g. "7 10 11 12 13" and I'd like to extract only the number "7".

Thank you.

Comment: `"7"` is a string, not a number. `7` or `7.0` are numbers. Strings cannot be equal to numbers. Strings also cannot be greater than or less than numbers. Strings are not numbers

Comment: I don't think that "python is unable to iterate over floats" is your problem.  That statement makes no sense.  If you had a list of floats, Python could certainly iterate over that list.  I'm guessing that the problem is that you haven't properly processed the data in the CSV file to allow what you're asking for.  You should show us what **test.apply()** does and what **input_value** looks like.

Comment: as an example, if you have a column with a value like "7 10 11 12 13", you would want to split that value up into unique numbers.  That's easy to do in this case, with **"7 10 11 12 13".split(' ')**.  Then you'd have a list, and you could say **if "7" in myList:**, for example.  This does not require treating "7" like a number.  If you don't need to do arithmetic, or compare two quantities, these things can possibly remain strings.  Just to go the next step, if you DID want numbers, you could do this:  **myList = [float(x) for x in "7 10 11 12 13".split(' ')]** and you'd have a list of floats.

Comment: If the column contains string-formatted lists of numbers as shown, then `apply` is completely unnecessary, as is `split`. `df['col1']=df['col'].str.contains('7')` avoids iterating at all

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correclty you have a string that represents a list of int seperated by spaces.
Therefore you would need to split(' ') and then check if 7 is there ?

e.g

```
 set_of_int = set(text.split(' '))
 seven_is_in = ("7" in set_of_int)
```

or

```
set_of_int = set(map(int,text.split(' ')))
seven_is_in = (7 in set_of_int)
```

Comment: set_of_int will not be a set of ints in this case, because split() is going to give you a list of strings.  So for this to work with the smallest change, you'd want **("7" in list_of_int)**.  What you probably want is **set([int(x) for x in text.split(' ')])**

Comment: Yes sorry , was aiming for "7" , wrote too fast, will correct

Answer (score 0):

It's this simple I think:

```
def check_has_refrigerator(input_value):
    if "7" in input_value.split(' '):
        return True
    return False
```

assuming that input_value looks like "7 10 11 12 13".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I'm pretty new to python so my apologies for not being so clear with the initial question Steven! It works now, I used G.Anderson's approach. Thank you!